# How to mock Sitecore Context Data in LayoutService for JSS disconnected mode?

Tags: jss

Where can I usually mock (for JSS disconnected mode) additional layout service data that I put into the layoutservice response by a "JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor".

So if I add additional context data like canonical links urls to the output like (see languageSwitch) :

```
"sitecore": {
               "context": {
                   "pageEditing": false,
                   "user": {
                       "domain": "sitecore",
                       "name": "admin"
                   },
                   "site": {
                       "name": "JssReactWeb"
                   },
                   "pageState": "normal",
                   "language": "en",
                   "languageSwitch": {
                       "de": "http:\u002F\u002Fmyweb\u002Fde\meineseite",
                       "en": "http:\u002F\u002Fmyweb\u002Fen\mypage"
                   },

               },
```

Answer (score 3):

See:
In `disconnected-mode-proxy.js`:

```
const proxyOptions = {
  appRoot: __dirname,
  ...,
  customizeContext: (context, route, currentManifest, request, response) => {
    context.languageSwitch = { ... }
  },
};
```